# Authorizing a deeply nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have nested resources that looks like this;

```
 resources :users do     
    resources :businesses do
      resources :business_accounts, path: "business_account", only: [:show] do 
        resources :business_withdraws
        resources :business_deposits
      end
    end
  end
```

I am unable to access the links `/users/1/businesses/2/business_account/1/business_deposits/new` and other routes of business deposits.

I have tried this and which gives us an error,

```
can [:read, :create], BusinessDeposit, business: {business_account:{user_id: user.id}}         
    can [:read, :create], BusinessWithdraw, business: {business_account:{user_id: user.id}}
```

and then this,

```
       can [:read, :create], BusinessDeposit do |deposit|
            deposit.business_account_id == user.business.business_account.id
        end
        can [:read, :create], BusinessWithdraw do |withdraw| 
            withdraw.business_account_id ==  user.business.business_account.id
        end
```

which simply makes it unaccessible

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :business
end
class Business < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_one :business_account
end
class business_account < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :business
    has_many :business_withdraws
    has_many :business_deposits
end
```

Comment: @IS04, user has_one :business and business has_one :business_account

Comment: in this case why you use `resources`?

Comment: @IS04, works else where

Comment: it works, but `/users/1/businesses/business_account/business_deposits/..` looks better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try:

```
can [:read, :create], BusinessDeposit, business_account: {business: {user: user}}
```

Comment: There is has_one :business relationship with the use. Please edit to reflect that...

Comment: Thank you. However when i try to access the link `http://localhost:3000/users/1/businesses/2/business_account/1/business_withdraws/new` i get `You are not authorized to access this page.`